# Encode string from Arabic Windows-1256 to Plain text objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Please how to convert Arabic string encode with `Arabic Windows-1256` like this one  :
`ÝÖíáÉ ÇáÔíÎ Ï:ãÍãÏ ÓÚíÏ ÑÓáÇä - ÍÈ ÇáÏäíÇ æØæá ÇáÃãá`
to plain text or utf-8.

**Update** 
I'm getting the string from radio metadata. when I try this  : `NSLog("%@",metadata);` I get this output :

```
metadata {
    IcecastStationName = "Rslan.com";
    StreamTitle = "\U00dd\U00d6\U00ed\U00e1\U00c9 \U00c7\U00e1\U00d4\U00ed\U00ce \U00cf:\U00e3\U00cd\U00e3\U00cf \U00d3\U00da\U00ed\U00cf \U00d1\U00d3\U00e1\U00c7\U00e4 - \U00ce\U00c7\U00d1\U00cc\U00e6\U00e4 \U00e6\U00ce\U00e6\U00c7\U00d1\U00cc !!";
}
```

And this is screen cap of my metada :
[image]
**Update**

This is my code :

```
self.audioController.onMetaDataAvailable = ^(NSDictionary *metaData) {
        NSString *temp = metaData[@"StreamTitle"];
        NSLog(@"1- metadata string : %@", temp);

        temp = [self stringToUnicode:temp];
        NSLog(@"2- metadata string to unicode : %@", temp);

        temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u00" withString:@"\\x"];
        NSLog(@"3- metadata unicode to escaped : %@", temp);

        const char *tempChar = [temp UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"4- metadata unicode escaped to char (tempChar) : %s", tempChar);

        NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:tempChar length:sizeof(tempChar) encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic)];

        NSLog(@"5: final conversion %@", s);


    };

/////////////
    -(NSString*) stringToUnicode:(NSString*)string
    {

        // convert to encoded unicode
        // do this by getting the data for the string
        // in UTF16 little endian (for network byte order)
        NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        size_t bytesRead = 0;
        const char* bytes = data.bytes;
        NSMutableString* encodedString = [NSMutableString string];

        // loop through the byte array
        // read two bytes at a time, if the bytes
        // are above a certain value they are unicode
        // otherwise the bytes are ASCII characters
        // the %C format will write the character value of bytes
        while (bytesRead < data.length)
        {
            uint16_t code = *((uint16_t*) &bytes[bytesRead]);
            if (code > 0x007E)
            {
                [encodedString appendFormat:@"\\u%04x", code];
            }
            else
            {
                [encodedString appendFormat:@"%C", code];
            }
            bytesRead += sizeof(uint16_t);
        }

        // done
        return encodedString;
    }
```

And this is my console log :

```
2015-05-01 22:08:57.065 Raslan Radio[4434:156945] 1- metadata string : ÝÖíáÉ ÇáÔíÎ Ï:ãÍãÏ ÓÚíÏ ÑÓáÇä - ÇáãÚÇÕí ææÌæÈ ÇáÊæÈÉ
2015-05-01 22:08:57.065 Raslan Radio[4434:156945] 2- metadata string to unicode : \u00dd\u00d6\u00ed\u00e1\u00c9 \u00c7\u00e1\u00d4\u00ed\u00ce \u00cf:\u00e3\u00cd\u00e3\u00cf \u00d3\u00da\u00ed\u00cf \u00d1\u00d3\u00e1\u00c7\u00e4 - \u00c7\u00e1\u00e3\u00da\u00c7\u00d5\u00ed \u00e6\u00e6\u00cc\u00e6\u00c8 \u00c7\u00e1\u00ca\u00e6\u00c8\u00c9
2015-05-01 22:08:57.065 Raslan Radio[4434:156945] 3- metadata unicode to escaped : \xdd\xd6\xed\xe1\xc9 \xc7\xe1\xd4\xed\xce \xcf:\xe3\xcd\xe3\xcf \xd3\xda\xed\xcf \xd1\xd3\xe1\xc7\xe4 - \xc7\xe1\xe3\xda\xc7\xd5\xed \xe6\xe6\xcc\xe6\xc8 \xc7\xe1\xca\xe6\xc8\xc9
2015-05-01 22:08:57.065 Raslan Radio[4434:156945] 4- metadata unicode escaped to char  : \xdd\xd6\xed\xe1\xc9 \xc7\xe1\xd4\xed\xce \xcf:\xe3\xcd\xe3\xcf \xd3\xda\xed\xcf \xd1\xd3\xe1\xc7\xe4 - \xc7\xe1\xe3\xda\xc7\xd5\xed \xe6\xe6\xcc\xe6\xc8 \xc7\xe1\xca\xe6\xc8\xc9
2015-05-01 22:08:57.065 Raslan Radio[4434:156945] 5: final conversion \xdd\xd6
```

Comment: Where is the Arabic text coming from? Show some relevant code in your question.

Comment: You didn't really answer rmaddy. What stored the string in `metaData` under the key `@"StreamTitle"`? How did that code create the string? From what source data? Go back to the beginning — the first point where the data entered your program from an external source — and log that data. Show each step of how you're interpreting it.

Comment: @KenThomases check my update, and I don't have acces to back-end all what I got is the url of radio.  
Also why when I print the metada I get the **streamtitle** in unicode but when I print **metadata[@"StreamTitle"]** the non unicode version (and in the pic the value of streamtitle also is not unicode version)

Comment: But `metadata` is already a dictionary at that point. How did you create that dictionary and from what? This is not the first place where the data entered your program. Are you using a third-party library or framework which is creating that dictionary? Or are you getting it from, for example, a network request, which would presumably give you data (not a string) which you would interpret in some way (e.g. JSON)?

Comment: @KenThomases Yes I'm using third party for radio stream( https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer ) but it has no relation with the string encoding. If you check this link http://www.rslan.com/RadioRslan.php you will see that even on the radio website the string is encoded in **Windows-1256**

Comment: Right, but if you get a byte stream which is Windows-1256-encoded text, you deal with that in one way (and it's straightforward). On the other hand, if you're getting a byte stream which really has 2 bytes per character, but they are just the Window-1256-encoded characters extended from a single byte to two, padded with zero, for no good reason, then you have to use complicated code to undo that stupidity. So, it's important to know what you're really getting.

Comment: If you want me to look at FreeStreamer and figure out what's happening, you have to show how you're using it. What is the simplest complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @KenThomases Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76737/discussion-between-chlebta-and-ken-thomases).

Comment: I will send you sample of my code

Answer (score 0):

Look at the methods in NSString. You can convert a C string to an NSString*, using any one of about 100 different character encodings.

Comment: Thanks which function allow encoding in NSString ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSString` methods or use toll-free-bridge from `CFString`.

```
NSStringEncoding arabicEnc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic);
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:"your arabic string" length:(NSInteger)10 encoding:arabicEnc];
NSLog(@"my UTF-8 string = %s",str.UTF8String);
```

10 is length of bytes of "your arabic string".

You don't need to unescape your string, `\U` just means that it points to some unicode code-point.

If your whole file is in that encoding then you can also use:

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding) error:(NSError **)error];
```

Comment: InitWithBytes:... This mean i have to convert my string to bytes :/ Check my update

Comment: 1. How did you create your dictionary? Thats where the magic lies.


2. How do you know its Windows-1256 encoding

Comment: Because I'm getting this dictionary from the radio URL and on the radio Webpage it's written that the title encoded with windows 1256 . Please read the comments on the answer post